# Android App Indexing is not working - click on google search link still need to choose apps

Tags: android, mobile, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I have implement app indexing for Android using this [guide](http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking), my apps have been tested using this [method](http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking#4). This apps has been deployed to Google Playstore 2 weeks ago. My website's header also been added some source code using this [guide](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish).

However, when i do search for google mobile, i dont find app indexing work. Because **install button** or any links to google playstore does not appear and **when i clicked link to my website, it was not automatically go to my apps but appear a pop up where i need to choose my app amoung others choice**.

What's wrong with my app indexing ?

Comment: can you able to find your app in playstore

Comment: https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app?hl=en

Comment: Do you still have a problem or did you managed to solve this?

Comment: @StanCtI still have a problem, i will inform you soon regarding this...

Comment: Do you still have a problem? If yes, are your apps in Production with the App Indexing implementation?